# Error Running SharePoint 2010 Product Configuration Wizard

Tags: 2010, error, central-administration, installation

I'm encountering an error when running the SharePoint 2010 Product Configuration Wizard that setups up central admin. I'm installing SharePoint on a Windows 7 Dev Environment (OS: Enterprise SP1). The configuration wizard has failed numerous times and I've been able to get past it. However, I have an error now that I can't seem to find a solution for:

```
Failed to register SharePoint services. An exception oftype  
System.InvalidOperationException was thrown. Additional exception 
information: Cannot startservice DCLoadBalancer14 on computer.
```

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you start the service with display name

> "Document Conversions Load Balancer for Microsoft SharePoint Server
>   2010"

manually from "Services.msc" .

From it , it looks like you are having an access issue .
Make sure you have appropriate rights and check if you have full admin rights in the local system.

Answer (score 0):

http://geeklit.blogspot.mx/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-config-wizard-error.html --

Check this url it may helps.

Comment: I took a look at the article. It doesn't appear to be the same error message that we are experiencing? Are you thinking its a related issue involving permissions?